# Java collections and objects assignment

Tags: java, object, collections

I have Floor class and it has following methods.

Passenger class has a constructor that sets current floor of residence to 1.

Following line adds passengers to the floor.

This is where I am struggling. Both of the following statements return true when I never loaded passenger on floor3.

Again, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code?  I have my suspicions as to what the problem is, but there isn't enough information here to confirm.

Comment: I have added more code, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever do anything with the ground floor... I suspect there are other problems in the code as well.

```
public boolean isResident(Passenger passenger) {
  int floor = building.getFloor();
  return building.floor(0).resident.contains(passenger);
}
```

This method calls `builder.getFloor()`, then proceeds to completely disregard the output, and check if the ground floor contains the passenger.

```
public void enter(Passenger passenger) {     
  Floor.enterGroundFloor(passenger);    
}
```

This method, also, summarily puts passengers on the ground floor.

So:

```
Building.floor(1).enter(p1) 

Building.floor(1).isResident(p1) --> true    
Building.floor(3).isResident(p1) --> true
```

This is natural because you are putting `p1` on the ground floor, and then checking if he is on the ground floor twice.

You appear to have some fundamental misconceptions about what `static` means, and how object hierarchy should be structured.  If you link the rest of your code, I am sure we can give you additional advice.

Comment: following line was suppose to have the floor that was passed in from building, its fixed now.  building.floor(0).resident.contains(passenger);

Comment: You still have multiple errors in your code - modifying static variables from local methods/constructors, `Building.enter()` is still wrong...  What is the output now with `.floor(0)` changed?

Comment: it is still true doesn't matter what floor I am checking for. All floor .isResident(p1) is true.

Comment: Does `Floor` have an `enter` method?  Can we see that?  Why does `Floor` have a static `Building` object, where/when is that instantiated?  If you fire up a debugger, I am sure you will find that a lot of what you think is happening isn't really happening

Comment: Yeah, enterGroundFloor, which is given above. Can you explain me something. If floor has a collection 'resident' and building is creating object floor such as 'floor1' 'floor2' then does following makes sense?

'floor1.resident.add(p1)'
'floor2.resident.add(p2)'

So does each floor has a collection resident where appropriate passengers are stored?

Comment: You should probably use an array, or List of floors... like you are doing now.  But it shouldn't be static, you are asking for trouble if you are using static references in instance methods